# do some action before displaying the message box, winforms

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I always use
`Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor`
for a time taking functions like hitting the DB.

Now if any exception occurs, I'll display the error message as:
`Msgbox(ex.Message)`

So before displaying any message, I need to reset the cursor to default.
Is there a simple way to do it at in one place instead of writing it in all catch blocks.

Is there a way to inherit MessageBox class and override the functions?

Other wise I need to code it in all the catch blocks or handle all the exceptions at one place which I don't want to modify the whole application now.

Thanks all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a common function like this, which accepts Exception as parameter and call this function in every catch block.

```
Try
'Do some code here
catch ex as Exception
ShowException(ex)
End Try


Private Sub ShowException(ex as Exception)
MessageBox.Show("An exception occured." + vbCrLf + ex.ToString())
Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

why you want to change the Cursor? I never favoured this (except in VBA :) )

why not use BackgroundWorker to do that work so that your GUI remains resposive. and maybe you could you little progressbase in StatusBar or dialog form to show the progress of the task ?

Comment: just noticed that it said MsgBox(), so it is VBA :). yuo might want to change your "tag" from "winforms" to  excel or vba

Comment: MsgBox is perfectly valid in VB.Net and Winforms